# How to provide an input to ftp terminal directly from the script

Tags: shell, ftp

I am trying to ftp a set of files to a client server. I tried automating it using ftp since we dont have SSH key setup yet. I have stored the destination host (Name, UN, PW) in .netrc file. When the script is executed, it opens up the ftp terminal and stops. How is it possible to continue the script post opening the ftp terminal ? Can you guys help ?

```
#!/bin/ksh
cd /scripts
. ./getYesterdayDate.sh
today=${YESTERDAY_DT}
today=`echo $today | sed 's/-//g'``
echo "Today is $today"

#Copying file from Source server
/usr/local/bin/scp UN@HOST:/backup/abc*.$today /scripts

#Renaming the files to custom names in the intermidatory server
cd /scripts
rm abc.data
touch abc.data
cat abc.data.$today >> abc.data
chmod a+r *

mv abc.START.$today abc.START
mv abc.END.$today abc.END

#FTPing to the DESTINATIONSERVER
/usr/bin/ftp DESTINATIONSERVERenter code here
cd /test
put abc.START
put abc.END
put abc.data
#In the above statements, when ftp is successful, instead of taking "cd /test" as input, terminal just stays at "ftp>"

echo "Upload for $today" | mailx -s "Successfull" name@domain.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the `.netrc` is correctly setup and the ftp command isn't prompting for credentials, then you can upload the files with:

```
echo put abc.START /test/abc.START | ftp DESTINATIONSERVER
echo put abc.END /test/abc.START | ftp DESTINATIONSERVER
echo put abc.data /test/abc.START | ftp DESTINATIONSERVER
```